# Day ticks for temporal data in R plot

Tags: r, plot

I have a frame with temperature data and the time it was read. It looks like this:

```
> head(dx)
                       t Temp
1218 2012-11-13 00:01:15   79
1219 2012-11-13 00:07:19   80
1220 2012-11-13 00:15:19   78
1221 2012-11-13 00:22:57   82
1222 2012-11-13 00:30:25   78
1223 2012-11-13 00:43:19   75
...
> tail(dx)
                       t Temp
2240 2012-11-17 13:37:19  106
2241 2012-11-17 13:43:23  106
2242 2012-11-17 13:49:25  106
2243 2012-11-17 13:55:25  106
2244 2012-11-17 14:00:00  107
2245 2012-11-17 14:06:23  107
```

I want to show it in a graph with ticks for every day. I use

```
plot(dx$t, dx$Temp/10)
```

to display the data, which works well, but the ticks shown on x-axis are too few. I would like to show one tick for each day. What's the best way to do it? There are many questions with slightly different requests, so I got lost. If this questions was asked already I would appreciate a link.

Comment: The `zoo` package will be helpful.  Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355042/label-x-axis-in-time-series-plot-using-r).

Comment: I looked at zoo and xts, but I don't have the time to read through all the documentation to really understand how they work :( This is a side project and can't allocate much time to it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to achieve this with base plots, but as Justin suggested, you could also look into packages that offer additional flexibility for plotting date objects, such as `zoo` and `xts`.

```
t <- seq(ISOdatetime(2012,1,1,11,10,25), ISOdatetime(2012,03,31,11,10,25), "hours")
dx <- data.frame(t=t, Temp=runif(length(t)))
plot(dx$t, dx$Temp/10, xaxt='n')
axis(1, at=as.POSIXct(unique(format(dx$t, '%Y-%m-%d')), format='%Y-%m-%d'),
     labels=unique(format(dx$t, '%Y-%m-%d')))
```

Comment: I tried this and doesn't work (doesn't show the ticks) :(. If I change the x data from date-time to just the date it shows the ticks, but of course all the temperature data is in one column, not as I want it. I feel I'm missing something elementary here...

Comment: Is dx$t a character string, or a POSIX object?

Comment: I've edited my answer with some fake data that hopefully better matches yours.

Comment: Yes! :) It works. Thank you! I used strptime to convert text to date/time - I'm not sure which format that would be